# Combine EXR images

Tags: image, imagemagick, openexr

I encountered some issues to combine EXR. With PNG or anything else, no problem (with ImageMagick).

I have 4 images at same size, which should be combined to get a bigger image. Each image represents a part of the bigger image (top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right). Each image contains N layers with information (colors, depth, etc). Theses layers must be combined in the final image.

Each image has this signature :

```
$ identify imput_tile_0001.exr
imput_tile_0001.exr EXR 400x225 400x225+0+0 16-bit DirectClass 2.501MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

I try ImageMagick simple commands like

```
$ convert +append *.exr out.exr
$ montage *.exr -tile 2x2 -geometry +0+0 out.exr
```

Theses commands returns a totally black image, with the correct size, and with only 1 layer.

I am open to any solution with any language or any software, working on Debian.

Edit :
The 4 EXR tiles can be found here :
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p6h8kh5wlroy5bb/AACMuR8WieZ-SqB3qXHFwk_ea?dl=0
(These are the "imput_tile...exr").

Any idea?

Comment: Works fine with `ImageMagick 6.9.1-6 Q16 x86_64 2015-06-26`

Comment: I created my input files with `convert -size 400x225 xc:red a1.exr` and `convert -size 400x225 xc:blue a2.exr` etc.

Comment: I talk about Multilayered EXR @MarkSetchell . Your inputs have only 1 layer.

Comment: Please share yours then.

Comment: I suspect multilayer EXR is not supported but am happy to be proved wrong... http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=26741

Comment: Two (different) dummy multi-layer ones will be fine if you can't share your actual images.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I edited my post to share the .EXR.

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work yet...

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry. OK now.

Comment: Your four EXR images seem to be blank. I see r = g = b = 0, alpha = 1 for all pixels in all images. I tried in nip2 and exrdisplay.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on (ok, I have never even seen any) EXR format images but I know that `vips` is able to process them. I can't even tell what your images look like but I think/hope this might be doing what you want.

First, I inspect your images and see they are 4 bands of 400x225 pixels like this

```
vips im_printdesc input_tile_0000.exr
400x225 float, 4 bands, srgb, setbuf VipsImage (0x7fda0984f000) count=1 9600 bytes
width: 400
height: 225
bands: 4
format: 6 - float
coding: 0 - none
interpretation: 22 - srgb
xoffset: 0
yoffset: 0
xres: 1.000000
yres: 1.000000
filename: "input_tile_0000.exr"
```

Then I do a `left-right join` to get the top row of your desired result:

```
vips im_lrjoin *0.exr *1.exr top.v
```

Then I do another `left-right join` to get the bottom row of your desired result:

```
vips im_lrjoin *2.exr *3.exr bot.v
```

Then I do a `top-bottom join` to join the top and bottom to get the final result:

```
vips im_tbjoin top.v bot.v result.v
```

And if I look at it, it appears to have the correct dimensions and the same number of bands and coding as your originals:

```
vips im_printdesc result.v
800x450 float, 4 bands, srgb, openin VipsImage (0x7f975b84d010) count=1
width: 800
height: 450
bands: 4
format: 6 - float
coding: 0 - none
interpretation: 22 - srgb
xoffset: 0
yoffset: 0
xres: 1.000000
yres: 1.000000
filename: "result.v"
```

**Notes**

1. The `xyz.v` format is `vips`'s internal, efficient image format
2. `vips` is available with bindings to many languages - see the `vips` website [here](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/supported/current/doc/html/libvips/index.html).
3. It may be able to cache the intermediate files I create (`top.v` and `bot.v`), but I have no idea how
4. The `vips` maintainer is on SO as @user894763 and he may be able to throw more light on my musings - hopefully!

Comment: Hi Mark! Looks fine. The vips8 way is `vips join 0000.exr 0001.exr top.v horizontal`, it'd be a little quicker. vips does not have exr write, you'd need to use RAD or PFM or TIFF for output. If you want to avoid creating the two intermediate images, you'd need to use the Ruby / Python / Javascript / whatever bindings.

Comment: @user894763 Thanks again for your inputs. The lack of an EXR writer maybe rather defeats the object of this particular exercise :-(

Comment: Nice answer @MarkSetchell . Seems full of promise. I do all your operations (regardless to version, I have vips7). So now, how can I open this "vips" format ? Or better : how to "translate" it to EXR ?

Comment: @pierallard with recent imagemagick you can use "convert" to change vips to exr, or you can write something like .tif from vips. I think your input images are all black though, so you will get a black output.